# AHK how to stop timer immediately?

Tags: timer, autohotkey

```
SetTimer, Test, 1000
Return

Test:
Send, a
Sleep, 3000
Send, b
Sleep, 3000
Send, c
Sleep, 3000
Return

1::
Send, x
SetTimer, Test, Off
Return
```

If I press "1" on 5th second, result will be: "axbc"

How to make timer stop running its content immediately, so in case above result would be "ax"?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it by checking whether the hotkey has been triggered (via the `state` variable) after every sleep cycle

```
;state:=0 ;state is zero by default
SetTimer, Test, 1000
Return

Test:
Send, a
Sleep, 3000
if(state)
return
Send, b
Sleep, 3000
if(state)
return
Send, c
Sleep, 3000
Return

1::
Send, x
SetTimer, Test, Off
state := 1
Return
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats exactly what I'm trying to get rid of :)

Comment: I probably should clarify what I said in my post. When I said "after every sleep cycle", I meant after every time you had a `Sleep` statement in your original code (not after every time the `Test` subroutine completes a loop). As such, if you press the `1` key during the delay after the program sends the first `a`, the program would stop sending letters and the end result would be just `ax`. If this is not what you wanted, please clarify what you want the program to do.

Comment: @Spyre, I'm not exactly sure what the expected result is either, but I tested your code and it never stopped sending keystrokes for me until I closed the script.